# aws cloudfront with lambda function origin throws 'The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"'

Tags: amazon-web-services, mime-types, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular universal app (SSR) on a lambda function, everything works fine with sls-offline and I have also published it as 'dev' version on a subdomain for testing. The exact same app.

The other app, has the custom domain tied to the api gateway (and therefore no way to redirect http to https) and works fine.

The cloudfront one is throwing:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

for all my script files.

My lambda handler has a valid configuration for the following mime types:

```
const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/json',
  'application/octet-stream',
  'application/xml',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/gif',
  'text/comma-separated-values',
  'text/css',
  'text/html',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/plain',
  'text/text',
  'text/xml',
  'image/x-icon',
  'image/svg+xml',
  'application/x-font-ttf'
];
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem, were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @ChrisGilardi sadly no -- have quit using aws + lambda altogether after that